# Trouble with scraping HTML, JS, from Odysee using requests_html

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

So, I succesfully used requests_html to render javascript for Dailymotion.com, now I tried the same with Odysee.com, but using render gives me just a big data mess with nothing that relates to the search I make there.

I suppose that rendering the javascript is just not the right way to get data from Odysee. But maybe somebody knows what WOULD be a way?

I'll post my code, and below that a little excerpt from the data that is obtained:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def search(search_terms):
    session = HTMLSession()
    url = f"https://odysee.com/$/search?q={search_terms}"
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
    try:
        resp = session.get(url, timeout=10, headers=headers)
    except:
        return "connection error"
    resp.html.render()
    print(resp.html.html)
    print(resp.html.text)

search("clannad")
```

Data mess:

```
   <script src="/public/ui-202302061938.f1d5d3f511.js" async=""></script>
  <style type="text/css">:root{--breakpoint-medium: 1150px}[dir=ltr] .pulse{animation:pulse 2s infinite ease-in-out}[dir=rtl] .pulse{animation:pulse 2s infinite ease-in-out}.header{z-index:3;position:fixed;top:0;width:100vw;font-size:var(--font-body);user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-webkit-app-region:drag;-webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(4px);backdrop-filter:blur(4px)}[dir] .header{background-color:var(--color-header-background)}.header button.skip-button{opacity:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden}[dir=ltr] .header button.skip-button{left:0;margin-right:var(--spacing-l)}[dir=rtl] .header button.skip-button{right:0;margin-left:var(--spacing-l)}.header button.skip-button:focus{opacity:1;position:relative;overflow:unset;width:unset;height:unset}.header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance{transition:border-radius .4s}[dir=ltr] .header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance .button__label{margin-left:var(--spacing-xxs) !important}[dir=rtl] .header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance .button__label{margin-right:var(--spacing-xxs) !important}.header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance:hover .button__label{color:var(--color-odysee-contrast) !important}@media(max-width: 1600px){[dir] .header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance-round{border-radius:50%}.header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance-round .button__label{display:none}}@media(max-width: 900px){.header .header__menu--right .header__navigationItem--balance-round{width:var(--height-button-mobile);height:var(--height-button-mobile)}}[dir=ltr] .header .header__menu--right .channel-thumbnail .comment__badge{left:20%}[dir=rtl] .header .header__menu--right .channel-thumbnail .comment__badge{right:20%}.header .header__menu--right .channel-thumbnail .comment__badge .icon{width:10px}[dir] .header .header__menu--right .channel-thumbnail .comment__badge .icon{margin-bottom:0px}.header .button--link{color:var(--color-odysee) !important}.header .button--link:hover{color:var(--color-link-hover) !important}.header .button--primary{color:var(--color-odysee-contrast) !important}[dir] .header .button--primary{background-color:var(--color-odysee) !important}[dir=ltr] .header .comment__badge{padding-right:var(--spacing-xxs)}[dir=rtl] .header .comment__badge{padding-left:var(--spacing-xxs)}.header .comment__badge .icon{width:18px}[dir] .header .comment__badge .icon{margin-bottom:-4px}@media(max-width: 900px){.header .card__actions--between .header__menu--left,.header .card__actions--between .header__menu--right{width:5rem;min-width:5rem}}.header *:focus-visible:not(.wunderbar__input):not(.menu__list):not(.menu__list--header):not(.button--secondary):not(.button-like):not(.button-dislike):not(select):not(input):not(textarea):not(video){color:var(--color-text) !important}[dir] .header *:focus-visible:not(.wunderbar__input):not(.menu__list):not(.menu__list--header):not(.button--secondary):not(.button-like):not(.button-dislike):not(select):not(input):not(textarea):not(video){background-color:rgba(var(--color-primary-static), 0.2) !important;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px var(--color-odysee) inset}.header *:focus-visible:not(.wunderbar__input):not(.menu__list):not(.menu__list--header):not(.button--secondary):not(.button-like):not(.button-dislike):not(select):not(input):not(textarea):not(video) .icon{stroke:var(--color-text) !important}[dir] .header select:focus-visible, [dir] .header input:focus-visible:not(.wunderbar__input), [dir] .header textarea:focus-visible{box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px var(--color-odysee) inset}[dir] .header .ff-container canvas{border-radius:50%}.header .ff-container .freezeframe-img{width:var(--height-button) !important;height:var(--height-button) !important}[dir]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, by looking around at the Headers that are send and received, I found this link:

https://lighthouse.odysee.tv/search?s=YOURQUERYHERE&size=20&from=0&claimType=f

which generates a JSON object with names and "claimId"s. To search them, one just uses odysee.com/name:ClaimId

Additional information here:
https://github.com/searx/searx/issues/2504